# Recursive function to add a node at the end of a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

Below is a recursive function I've written to add a node at the end of a linked list. Could anyone tell whether the function is correct or not?

```
Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int data){  
     if(head.next == null){  
             Node temp= new Node(data);        
             head.next= temp;  
             return;  
        }  
 insertAtEnd(head.next, data);  
}
```

There's already a class called **Node** which has been defined as below:

```
class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) {data = d; next = null; }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you run it and see

Comment: recursion is nice concept to describe some context, then design algorithm - but not here. Try to speak innatural laguage like to people: nothing here is recursve

Comment: Hint: an **essential** part of programming a data structure is to **test** the implementation. Ideally you write test cases *before* even writing your production code ... seriously: asking others to review your code should be like the *last* thing you do ... before that, you do a ton of things *yourself* to answer that question. (asking is ok, but this community isn't ideal for such questions). And as said: you want to learn this stuff. And testing should be an **essential** part of your learning activities!

Comment: And honestly: the above shouldnt even compile. You can have a *return* statement without giving a value, but your method signature says to return a Node instance. Sorry pal, but before even thinking to put up code here for "review" - make sure it at least compiles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is neither a testing nor a code review service.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your response, certainly got to know something and my answer as well.

Comment: The tricky part right now is basically: do others share my view ... or will your question stay with that single downvote ... that would give you some guidance whether keeping the question is a good idea, or if it would be better to delete it. You see, this is a question/answer community, and the idea is that content is helpful to future readers searching for things. From that point of view, I am tempted to suggest that you delete your question. But I really leave that to you ...

Answer (score 2):

Your method has a `Node` return type, so you should return the new `Node`:

```
Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int data) {  
    if (head.next == null) {  
        Node temp= new Node(data);        
        head.next= temp;  
        return temp;  
    }  
    return insertAtEnd(head.next, data);  
}
```

or

```
Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int data) {  
    if (head.next == null) { 
        head.next = new Node(data);
        return head.next;  
    }  
    return insertAtEnd(head.next, data);  
}
```

Comment: @SambeetMandal If I thought my answer was incorrect, I wouldn't have posted it. Of course, if I were you, I'd run the code to make sure it works.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: One more thing I would like to add, why exactly are you returning temp in that if statement? I think setting the links should do fine. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SambeetMandal You were the one putting up that method signature. **You** decided that the insert method returns some Node instance. Eran just tries to make sense out of that.

Comment: Honestely, that last comment by the OP is why I decided to downvote and close request the question. Because he isn't looking for answers, he is looking for a tutor teaching him the details of his homework ...

Comment: @SambeetMandal if you don't want your method to return the newly inserted Node, you should change its return type to `void`.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for the response! Maybe I should do my homework all by myself.